# Make paypal form buy now form wider

Tags: html, paypal

Im trying to make a buy it now form with paypal. I cannot figure out how to widen a text input field.

This is my code currently:

```html
<h1>Simply fill in the info below</h1>
          <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="277G8E79U9AX6">
          <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
          <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="One week of Animal Photos">
          <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="7.95">
          <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
          <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
          <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
          <table>
          <tr><td><input style="width: 300px;" type="hidden" name="on0" value="Your Email">Your Email</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input style="width: 600px; height = 200px;" type="hidden" name="on1" value="Address of Recipient">Address of Recipient</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="300"></td></tr>
          </table>
          <tr><td><input style="width: 600px; height = 200px;" type="hidden" name="on2" value="Message">Message</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os2" maxlength="300"></td></tr>
          </table>
          <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
          </form>
```

I tried adding a `style = "width:300px"` or simply `width: "300px"` but it doesn't reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

You are styling the wrong inputs, look for the ones that doesn't have:

```
type="hidden"
```

And go for the ones that has type="text". Here is a version of it I made from your code:

```html
<h1>Simply fill in the info below</h1>
          <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="277G8E79U9AX6">
          <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
          <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="One week of Animal Photos">
          <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="7.95">
          <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
          <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
          <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
          <table>
          <tr><td><input style="width: 300px;" type="hidden" name="on0" value="Your Email">Your Email</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200" style="width: 500px;"></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input style="width: 600px; height = 200px;" type="hidden" name="on1" value="Address of Recipient">Address of Recipient</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="300" style="width: 500px;"></td></tr>
          </table>
          <tr><td><input style="width: 600px; height = 200px;" type="hidden" name="on2" value="Message">Message</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os2" maxlength="300" style="width: 500px;"></td></tr>
          </table>
          <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
          </form>
```

I hope it help, just in case, here is a pen: [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbEZOv)

Answer (score 0):

Use this and do style width in input.

```
<style>
input:focus::placeholder {
color: transparent;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
```